# d3.js reusable charts on multiple elements in same page

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I am working on developing charts based on d3.js framework. In [Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) they proposed conventional approach for developing reusable charts.

But I could not understand how the same `chart` object serves for rendering two different svg elements.

For example we say,

we have one chart object

```
function chart() {
  var width = 720, // default width
      height = 80; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return my;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return my;
  };

  return my;
}

var chartobject = chart().width(100);
```

Using same `chartobject`,Having two svg elements with id1,id2 i want to generate and update the charts

```
d3.select("#id1").data(data).call(chartobject)

d3.select("#id2").data(data).call(chartobject)
```

My question is here, if i want to `update the height of the chart or change any color properties` for the `svg#id2` alone after construction, what should i do? Is it possible? I dont want to reconstruct here. I just want to update the color of the chart!!
Please correct me if am doing anything wrong here .

Comment: You would need two different chart objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the charts you need two different chart objects.You can update the height and width by declaring `.height()` and `.width()` under `chart()`

```
var chartobject = chart().width(100).height(100)d3.select("#id1").data(data).call(chartobject);

var chartobject2 = chart().width(200).height(200)d3.select("#id2").data(data).call(chartobject2);
```